# How to programmatically focus view?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I read the [Supporting Focus Within Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH5-SW2) and I'm still missing how can I shift focus to some custom view programmatically.

I know there are `setNeedsFocusUpdate` and `preferredFocusedView` methods. However, I'm looking for a method like `[button bringIntoFocus]`.

Does something as simple as this exist?

Comment: Can you explain why setting `preferredFocusedView` and calling `setNeedsFocusUpdate` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: please accept an answer or explain why the current ones don't satisfy you.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such way, it all needs to be indirectly done. You configure the Focus-chain from the higher up view (or view controller) to end up on the view you need to be focused. So yes, you need to check state at every view/VC in between and grant preferred focus conditionally.

Comment: why was this answer downvoted? You may not like that there is no way (I don't, either) but that is hardly my fault, don't kill the messenger!